# problem with varying css height

Tags: css

I have got a div [projItemsContent] that varies in height based on the contents,the problem i have got is that there are two other divs [projItemsLeft,projItemsRigh] that i want to have the same height as projItemsContent div. Any suggestions please?

```
div.projItems{width:360px;min-height:200px;_height:200px;background:#000}

div.projItemsLeft{float:left;width:30px;background:#990}
div.projItemsRight{float:left;width:30px;background:#900}
div.projItemsContent{float:left;width:300px;background:#ccc}


<div class="projItems">


    <div class="projItemsLeft">&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="projItemsContent">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sit amet nunc eu ligula tincidunt faucibus. 
        Curabitur eget magna neque, sed porta sem. Fusce eu lorem at orci dapibus faucibus ut eu mi. In eget ligula risus. 
        Sed id lectus lorem. Integer elit dui, bibendum vitae dictum a, mollis sodales diam. Morbi vehicula lobortis semper. 
        Suspendisse potenti. Proin eu convallis lectus. Praesent ut sem at enim condimentum dictum vitae id elit. 
        Phasellus id dolor ante, hendrerit tempus lorem. Proin nisi nibh, convallis et sollicitudin in, interdum vitae nibh. 
        Fusce ullamcorper dictum nunc, eget bibendum ipsum viverra quis. Aliquam vitae leo non metus ultricies tempus in id libero. 
        Vivamus mauris tortor, convallis ut luctus at, elementum sed velit. Cras cursus tempus erat adipiscing lacinia. 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam diam risus, sollicitudin sed venenatis a, molestie in turpis.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sit amet nunc eu ligula tincidunt faucibus. 
        Curabitur eget magna neque, sed porta sem. Fusce eu lorem at orci dapibus faucibus ut eu mi. In eget ligula risus. 
        Sed id lectus lorem. Integer elit dui, bibendum vitae dictum a, mollis sodales diam. Morbi vehicula lobortis semper. 
        Suspendisse potenti. Proin eu convallis lectus. Praesent ut sem at enim condimentum dictum vitae id elit. 
        Phasellus id dolor ante, hendrerit tempus lorem. Proin nisi nibh, convallis et sollicitudin in, interdum vitae nibh. 
        Fusce ullamcorper dictum nunc, eget bibendum ipsum viverra quis. Aliquam vitae leo non metus ultricies tempus in id libero. 
        Vivamus mauris tortor, convallis ut luctus at, elementum sed velit. Cras cursus tempus erat adipiscing lacinia. 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam diam risus, sollicitudin sed venenatis a, molestie in turpis.


    </div>      

    <div class="projItemsRight">&nbsp;</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encapsulate the divs:

```
div.projItems{width:360px;min-height:200px;_height:200px;background:#000}

div.projItemsLeft{float:left;width:360px;background:#990}
div.projItemsRight{float:right;width:330px;background:#900}
div.projItemsContent{float:left;width:300px;background:#ccc}


<div class="projItems">


    <div class="projItemsLeft">
    <div class="projItemsRight">

    <div class="projItemsContent">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sit amet nunc eu ligula tincidunt faucibus. 
        Curabitur eget magna neque, sed porta sem. Fusce eu lorem at orci dapibus faucibus ut eu mi. In eget ligula risus. 
        Sed id lectus lorem. Integer elit dui, bibendum vitae dictum a, mollis sodales diam. Morbi vehicula lobortis semper. 
        Suspendisse potenti. Proin eu convallis lectus. Praesent ut sem at enim condimentum dictum vitae id elit. 
        Phasellus id dolor ante, hendrerit tempus lorem. Proin nisi nibh, convallis et sollicitudin in, interdum vitae nibh. 
        Fusce ullamcorper dictum nunc, eget bibendum ipsum viverra quis. Aliquam vitae leo non metus ultricies tempus in id libero. 
        Vivamus mauris tortor, convallis ut luctus at, elementum sed velit. Cras cursus tempus erat adipiscing lacinia. 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam diam risus, sollicitudin sed venenatis a, molestie in turpis.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sit amet nunc eu ligula tincidunt faucibus. 
        Curabitur eget magna neque, sed porta sem. Fusce eu lorem at orci dapibus faucibus ut eu mi. In eget ligula risus. 
        Sed id lectus lorem. Integer elit dui, bibendum vitae dictum a, mollis sodales diam. Morbi vehicula lobortis semper. 
        Suspendisse potenti. Proin eu convallis lectus. Praesent ut sem at enim condimentum dictum vitae id elit. 
        Phasellus id dolor ante, hendrerit tempus lorem. Proin nisi nibh, convallis et sollicitudin in, interdum vitae nibh. 
        Fusce ullamcorper dictum nunc, eget bibendum ipsum viverra quis. Aliquam vitae leo non metus ultricies tempus in id libero. 
        Vivamus mauris tortor, convallis ut luctus at, elementum sed velit. Cras cursus tempus erat adipiscing lacinia. 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam diam risus, sollicitudin sed venenatis a, molestie in turpis.


    </div>

    Right column content      

    <br style="clear:left;" /></div>

    Left column content

    <br style="clear:right;" /></div>

</div>
```

Comment: It ain't pretty but a quick solution. I suggest you stick with grahams answers. Especially holy grail layout by Matthew James Taylor (this is what I am using as a base in conjunction with YAML for new Drupal themes).

Comment: i got it working using jquery,but wanted to know if it was possible using basic CSS

Answer (score 0):

Google turned up this: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm

I once used this as a guide: http://bluerobot.com/web/layouts/layout3.html

And this too is a good resource: http://www.thenoodleincident.com/tutorials/box_lesson/boxes.html